# scala.util.Try: How to get Throwable value? Pattern matching?

Tags: scala, try-catch

The following REPL snippets presume:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
```

Why do these two statements not pass compilation? I get "constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type":

```
Failure(new Exception("a")) match {
  case Success(i) => "a"; case Failure(e) => "b"; case _ => "c"; }

Success(123) match {
  case Success(i) => "a"; case Failure(e) => "b"; case _ => "c"; }
```

I can get the success value out of a `Try` with `get` or `toOption`. Is there a corresponding way to get the failing `Throwable` value or `Option[Throwable]`?

EDIT: Casting from Failure/Success to Try works

```
Failure(new Exception("a")).asInstanceOf[Try[Int]] match {
  case Success(i) => "a"; case Failure(e) => "b"; case _ => "c"; }

Success(123).asInstanceOf[Try[Int]] match {
  case Success(i) => "a"; case Failure(e) => "b"; case _ => "c"; }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first snippet doesn't compile because `Success` isn't a subtype of `Failure`. The compiler thinks you're being silly, since the `Success(i)` case will never match.

To take a simpler example, this also doesn't compile.

```
Failure(new Exception()) match { case Success(_) => }
```

Neither does this, for the same reason.

```
42 match { case Success(_) => }
```

What you've written does nearly work, but the value you're matching has to have a more general type of `Try[_]` (which it would have anyway, if the pattern match were actually being used in some useful context).

```
(Failure(new Exception("a")): Try[_]) match {
    case Success(i) => "a"; case Failure(e) => "b"; case _ => "c"; }
```

Answer (score 23):

Consider this:

```
Try(1) match {
    case Success(i) => i
    case Failure(t) => 0 // t is the `Throwable`
}
```

This works because `Success` and `Failure` are sub classes of the abstract class `Try`. However, the following code fails to compile, because you're no longer matching on a generic `Try`, and instead a `Failure` which can *never* be an instance of `Success`.

```
Failure(new Exception("a")) match {
    case Success(i) => "a" // You can see it compiles if you remove this line.
    case Failure(e) => "b"
    case _ => "c"
}
```

This is like trying to match an `Integer` to a `String`, it doesn't really make sense.

If you want to get the `Throwable` via pattern matching, see the first snippet of code.

Another way you could extract the `Throwable` would be to use the `failed` method on your `Try`, which will wrap the `Throwable` from a failure within `Success`.

```
scala> val t: Throwable = Try(throw new Exception).failed.get
t: Throwable = java.lang.Exception
```

Calling this on a `Success`, however, will throw another exception.